# MFC View inset within the frame

Tags: c++, mfc

Why is the MFC client view inset inside the frame.

I am writing a MFC windows app with a single client view and when I have filled it thus:

```
CRect rcClient;
GetClientRect(&rcClient);
dc.FillRect(rcClient, &CBrush( RGB(128, 128, 128 ) ) );
```

however there is a thin white line on the right and bottom edges just inside the frame?

But I have an app I have developed using the Win32 API and that essentially uses the same
GetClientRect and FillRect functions. And its filled view react goes the the edge of the frame.
Thanks in advance imk

Comment: Remove the border by calling `CWnd::ModifyStyle` and/or `CWnd::ModifyStyleEx` on the `CView` instance.

Comment: turns out that in CChildView::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)  the MFC builder puts in cs.dwExStyle |= WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE; commenting this line out removes the client edge